# Finding child functions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to list child/sub functions for a given parent function in PowerShell? I have a function that calls multiple sub functions, which in-turn call some more functions.

Somewhere in this tree, one of the functions is failing. If I get a piece of code to list child functions for a given parent function, that would be a big help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes.  Look at the `$StackTrace` automatic variable after an exception is thrown.